# What does MLK mean by "lonely island" and "vast ocean"?

Tags: united-states, social-history, 1960s, civil-rights

In the speech, "[I have a dream](https://www.archives.gov/files/press/exhibits/dream-speech.pdf)", M.L. King says the following:

> *One hundred years later, the Negro lives on a **lonely island** of poverty in the midst of a **vast ocean** of material prosperity.*

What does he mean by "**lonely island**" and "**vast ocean**", what is he referring to here?

EDIT:

I am assuming that by "**lonely island**" he refers to the part of the country which the negro lived in and the "**vast ocean**" is the white people who ignore them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Martin Luther King Jr. is making the point that, while the United States had prospered and become the wealthiest nation on Earth, the overwhelming majority of black people in America were poor.

The racial divide in 1963 America was very much also a wealth divide:

[image: Income divide]

- [Source: Colin Gordon - [A Closer Look at Race and Inequality]](http://scalar.usc.edu/works/growing-apart-a-political-history-of-american-inequality/race-and-inequality)

(Of course, one might argue that little has changed in that regard!) [Segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racial_segregation_in_the_United_States) was, as I'm sure you are already aware, still very much the reality of life for millions of African Americans.

By using the analogy of *lonely islands of poverty* in a *vast ocean of material prosperity*, MLK was encouraging people to visualise that racial divide, and their segregated society, in those terms and to demand racial justice for mistreated African Americans.

Comment: What is "racial justice"? (I find that phrasing quite unlucky)

Comment: @LangLangC It's hardly a contentious term, and was one routinely [used by MLK](https://kinginstitute.stanford.edu/king-papers/documents/nonviolence-and-racial-justice) himself. For more background, see this [lesson](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-racial-justice-lesson-for-kids.html) for example.

Comment: @LangLangC You might also find MLK's 1961 lecture on [Racial justice and nonviolent resistance](https://www.chapman.edu/diversity/_files/who-we-are/racial-injustice-and-nonviolent-resistance.pdf) and his 1964 Nobel Lecture [The quest for peace and justice](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/peace/1964/king/lecture/) of interest.